# Finding data for 2 elements in a list java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Assume I have a data in .csv file as following:

```
         | Number | Data_1 |  Data_2  |
             1        Yes       No
             2        No        Yes
             3        Yes       Yes
```

My question is how can I implement a function to check if a Number has the data for both Data 1 and Data 2.

What I have so far:

```
 List<Data> csvList = new ArrayList<Data>();  

String number = null;
String data_1 = null;
String data_2 = null;

if(!csvList.isEmpty() && csvList.size() > 0){
  number = csvList.get(0);
  data_1 = csvList.get(1);
  data_2 = csvList.get(2);

 //..... Now what can we do now from here? 

}
```

MODIFIED: 10:38AM

---

SOLVED

Thanks

Comment: Loop though the list and check for the values. For complete ans share your data class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Data> hasBothData = new ArrayList<Data>();  
for(Data data:csvList){
    if(data.hasData1() && hasData2()) { // how ever you check for data validity.
       hasBothData.add(data);
    }
}
```

Your `hasBothData` should have all elements with the both data.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean hasData1 and hasData2 here? Are you creating another constructor?

Comment: If you share your code for Data class i can explain it to you better. In this case Its just an verbally telling you that you should put your conditions in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the file in line by line. (I'm assuming you haven't done this bit yet: there's no sign of it in your code.)

The easiest way, if your data is as simple as you've presented it, would be to read in a line and then use `String.split(",")` to split on the commas, or else a `Scanner` with the delimiter set to a comma. If you've got more complex data then you could use a [CSV parser](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) but it seems a bit over the top if your data is very simple and predictable and you don't need to handle quotation marks and so on.

Once you've done that, you can use the values you read in, and check that they're as they should be (use `"Yes".equals(s)`, etc.).

But you will need to explain more if you want more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Create object representing data( note that i changed name from data to CSV ):

```
class CSV { 
    public CSV(String number, String data1, String data2){
    this.number = number;
    this.data1 = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
    }
    String number;
    String data1;
    String data2;
    public String getNumber(){
    return this.number;
    }

    public boolean hasData(){
        if ( ( data1.equals("Yes" == true ) && (data2.equals("No" == true) )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then import data from csv to it ( ommited file operations ) :

```
List<Data> csvList = new ArrayList<CSV>();
```

Create result list with numbers. 
    List numbers = new ArrayList();

Then iterate over all entities.

```
for(CSV data:csvList){
    if ( data.hasData() ) 
        numbers.add(data.getNumber());
}
```

If data is not explicty Yes or No, then you have to know domain, so before compiling must know all answers, with solution. 
At a pinch, you may group answers in sets and add methods to guess what kind of data it is:

```
public boolean belongTo(String column) {
    if ( column.contains("Yes") == true ) 
        return true; 
    if ( column.contains("yes") == true ) 
        return true; 
    if ( column.contains("Ja") == true ) 
        return true; 
    return false;
}
```

You do the same for data2. 
Here is how to change Data class: 
Instead of

```
    if ( ( data1.equals("Yes" == true ) && (data2.equals("No" == true) )
```

put:

```
    if ( ( this.belongsTo(data1) == true ) && (this.belongsTo(data2) == true) )
```

Finally we have CSV class:

```
 class CSV { 
        public CSV(String number, String data1, String data2){
        this.number = number;
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        }
        String number;
        String data1;
        String data2;
        public String getNumber(){
        return this.number;
        }

        public boolean hasData(){
            if ( ( data1.equals("Yes" == true ) && (data2.equals("No" == true) )
                return true;
            return false;
        }
public boolean belongsTo(String column) {
    if ( column.contains("Yes") == true ) 
        return true; 
    if ( column.contains("yes") == true ) 
        return true; 
    if ( column.contains("Ja") == true ) 
        return true; 
    /* insert here your "Yes" equivalents */
    return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way if you don't explicitly say "Yes" or "No" in condition loop. What if there is a data not Yes or No?

Comment: i wrote the solution for this in an answer.